# Disabled item in NavigationView not showing as greyed out

Tags: android, material-design

When I add:

```
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawer_selector"
```

to:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

Then all the items have the `checked` and `unchecked` colors defined in `drawer_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#1F8674" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#323232" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

But when I disable 1 item in `activity_main_drawer.xml`:

```
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_local"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_signal_cellular_0_bar_black_24dp"
                android:title="@string/drawer_local" />
```

This item is not greyed out, but has the same color as the selectable items. So can I manually set the color back to this greyed out state? This seems to be a bug in material design? I tried the default Android Studio project with this theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

and the latest material design:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it more specific by adding `android:state_enabled` to the checked/unchecked states. And create a separate state for the disabled item; sounds like its color is `"#9E9E9E"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#1F8674" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="#323232" android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="#9E9E9E" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```